# Can't access framework code

Tags: ios, swift

I have a project that I've been working on for a while. Last week I decided to refactor the code by building my model objects and networking layer from the ground up in a new swift framework.

For instance, I had a `Restaurant` model object in my main project. I moved it into my new framework:

```
public struct Restaurant {
  public let id: Int
  public let name: String
}
```

After finishing the framework, I tried to re-integrate it back to the main project. I did the following:

1. Deleted all my files regarding the model types
2. Deleted my whole `Server` class, which housed all the networking code
3. Added the framework to the main project

However, for some reason, none of my types in my framework is being recognized in my main project. For instance:

```
import MyNewFramework

class TableView: UITableViewController {
  var restaurant: Restaurant! // error - Use of undeclared type 'Restaurant'
}
```

However, in a fresh brand new Xcode project, doing the same steps does compile.

At this point I think it's a matter of a week to rewrite everything into a new project... but I wish there's another solution. Any advice appreciated!

Thanks!